# Unable to get accurate direction using Bearing in Android

Tags: java, android, geolocation, bearing

I need my app to fetch the direction using Bearing and put it on the map with my custom Icon facing the fetched direction. Right now, it shows the wrong direction. I need to make it work like Uber or Lyft 's car icon rotation plotted on Map. Please Suggest if my approach is correct or wrong. 
Currently I am fetching direction and displaying icon on the same app for testing.

This is what I am doing:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    LatLng latlng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    CameraPosition cameraPOsition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(latlng).zoom(15f).build();
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().flat(true).position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPOsition));
    Marker m = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.car)).rotation(location.getBearing()).anchor(0.5f, 0.5f));
    m.setPosition(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
}
```

Comment: Before use bearing you need to verify if bearing data is not 0.0. Note: Bearing data is relative to orizontal direction and isn't related to device orientation.

Comment: I'm getting 0,0 most of the time. Well, is there any other way around to get the directional data in order to make my icon rotate ?

Comment: 0,0 means that location does not have a bearing. Here the android documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getBearing%28%29

Comment: 0.0 can be a valid bearing if the device is moving exactly towards north. Instead the `Location.hasBearing()` method should be used to check if there's  a valid bearing available. To have a bearing you must move first so test outside by walking or driving. And you should probably check was the location GPS based or cell tower based and only use bearings from GPS based location updates.

Comment: I have no idea to workaround if the gps does not return the bearing.